# Installing NodeJS on windows machine?

Tags: javascript, webserver, node.js

How do I Install node.js on my windows Machine?? I Searched All the available blogs for info, I found none of them are useful. so Is it possible for me to install `node.js` on my windows machine. If the answer is yes can anyone please explain the procedure. BTW
I'm using **windows XP**

Comment: Just for people coming into this question from google, nodejs now has a windows version but it's in development. head over to their website and check  it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to get Node running perfectly well on XP by using Cygwin. [These instructions](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)) worked well for me.

It's worth noting that there is now a [native Node.JS port for Windows](https://nodejs.org/download/). Use that rather than stuff with CygWin.

Comment: Here is the correct link: http://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29

Comment: Seriously? Time to fork and start building a windows port!

Comment: Here's some really cool, relevant news: Microsoft is helping Joyent port Node.JS to Windows: http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/06/microsoft-is-helping-joyent-po.php

Answer (score 13):

They now have node.exe that you can download and run directly, no need for cygwin. See nodejs.org.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the easiest way is to get nodejs binaries from http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/. It has the required dependencies like Cygwin, etc. Also you can run `npm` using command:-

```
> shell.cmd
> node npm install < package_name >
```

In the current verion (0.4.1) `npm` may give DNS error. It is simple to fix. Just create `etc` folder in the install folder and in `etc` create a file `resolv.conf` with the following contents.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're having trouble trying to install NodeJS on windows I've posted a guide on how to install using Cygwin. Hope it helps! [Installing NodeJS on Cygwin in Windows or on Ubuntu Server 10.04](http://www.lucashills.com/articles/3)

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to install node without having Cygwin. It's actually very simple to do. You can find the instructions here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation.

I did the manual installation (https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#manual-install), and it was painless, and worked like a charm.

Comment: I found this question when I was looking for the answer, so I thought it'd be useful to have an updated answer for people wondering how to do that.

Comment: +1 for your efforts then, keep up the good work .. Good day! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can download and run directly from this link https://nodejs.org/download/

To check whether nodejs is installed or not , open command prompt and type `node -v`, It will show nodejs version

Comment: Writing `(AT)Avinash` inside the answer doesnt work, only inside comment. If you want to link a user inside an answer you can link his profile but he wont receive a notification.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some instructions which we've found to work:

https://github.com/balupton/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js

It uses some pre-built binaries which package NPM and Node.js together.

Answer (score 1):

You can just download node.exe from http://node.js and then use node & npm from cmd.exe (search it on the menu)

```
$  node
$  node file.js
$  npm
$  npm install
```

Comment: Have you read this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447063/installing-nodejs-on-windows-machine/29737441#comment8663328_3447063) before answering? :) I appreciate your effort and initiative though

Comment: Yes, but it is so small, most of the people miss those types of comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you can download NodeJS from: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Run the downloaded installer
3. After installation completes, open a command prompt, and run the following command to ensure NodeJS is correctly installed.

   ```
   node --version
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below steps for installation on the node.js and running as server

1) Download the suitable installation package for windows from following path https://nodejs.org/en/download/

2)Install the Package by Running the package file.

3)After installations click on Start>All Programs>Node.js>Node.js command prompt
[image]

4)In Node.js command prompt>Run following command "npm install -g http-server"

5)Now navigate to your project folder eg: d:>test> and run "http-server".you will be able to run project on your ip eg: http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all check in your system node is install or not
If node is install then follow this steps.
on the project location hit these command
Step 1 =>mkdir node_project    
      (to create the folder node_project)
Step 2 =>npm init 
      (to create package.json)
Step 3 =>npm install express
      (install node module)
 Step 4 => touch index.js
      (to create the js file. in this file you can create you own code)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).